# Helmholtz free energy for a first order phase transition

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I know how entropy and specific heat for constant pressure, how both of these quantities change when we are observing the first order phase transition. I want to ask if someone can illustrate (with a graph) how the Helmholtz free energy changes when we are on a first order phase transition. I cannot find a graphic representation of it. And it definitely changes because :

When a system can be in one of the different phases: a or b we have:

$(\frac {\partial \mu_a} {\partial T})_P =/=  (\frac {\partial \mu_b} {\partial T})_P$. This means that the free energy changes when there is a phase transition. So how does it change?

Comment: Does this help https://users.aber.ac.uk/ruw/teach/334/phtr-order.php ? On the figures, the bold lines are the "real" free energy (well it's the free enthalpy, but they look the same) while the thin ones are the continuation of the free energy in the phase in which they don't minimize the "global" free energy. So at the phase transition, the free energy "breaks" (but is still continuous).

Comment: @Syrocco the link seems broken

Comment: Oh it works for me : / It doesn't load?

Comment: It works for me too. Now one question: Since G= F+ PV then it's the first graph the one that concerns me, correct?

Comment: Yes, the top left one.

Comment: Yeah, that's it, thank you

Comment: @Syrocco I get a "Proxy error" from Server at users.aber.ac.uk Port 443 Reason: DNS lookup failure for: cgi-enabler-ruw

Comment: @Syrocco The question is about the Helmholtz free energy, not the Gibbs free energy. They aren't the same! If the volume at constant pressure changes during the phase change (which is typically the case), then $\Delta F=\Delta G-P\Delta V=-P\Delta V\neq0$, which means the curve is not continuous.

Comment: @Chemomechanics Oh yes you are right I didn’t think about that and just to be sure, it means that usually, at constant volume, if the pressure changes at the phase transition, while $F$ is continuous $G$ isn’t ?

Comment: Agreed; from $dF=-S\,dT-P\,dV+\sum_i\mu N_i=\sum_i\mu N_i$ at constant temperature and volume, $\Delta F=0$ for isothermal, isochoric phase transitions (but generally not for isothermal, isobaric phase transitions).